# How to remove an object from an array when a UIButton is tapped in swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, parse-platform, uibutton

I'm currently creating a quiz game and I want there to be a hint feature button.  Right now I'm getting the data for the quiz game from Parse.com and saving it in a local array.  Each time the hint button is pressed I want it to eliminate one of the wrong answers from the array and the hide the corresponding button to that answer.

```
  @IBOutlet var Button1: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var Button2: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var Button3: UIButton!
  @IBOutlet var Button4: UIButton!

  var question: String!
  var answers: [String]!
  var answer: String!
```

The answer string is in form of "1","2","3","4" corresponding to their place in  the answers array. Any help will be appreciated!

This is a sample function I'm using but instead of hiding the wrong answer buttons it hides the right answer button!

```
 func giveHint(sender: UIButton){ 
if self.answer != "1" { answers.removeAtIndex(1) Button1.alpha = 0 } else if self.answer != "2" { answers.removeAtIndex(2) Button2.alpha = 0 } else if self.answer != "3" { answers.removeAtIndex(3) Button3.alpha = 0 } else if self.answer != "4" { answers.removeAtIndex(4) Button4.alpha = 0 } 
}
```

It works using D Greg's answer below.  The only difference was the string had to be converted to an Int.  This was done by Int(string).

Comment: Are the answers on the buttons or labels and buttons?

Comment: The answers are on the buttons

Comment: @nhgrif lol! All must unwrapped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the buttons to an array and hide the button on a hint tap. This code assumes that the buttons and answers are in the same order.

```
@IBOutlet weak var btn1: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn2: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn3: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var btn4: UIButton!

var question: String!
var wrongAnswers: [String]!
var answer: String!
var btnsArray = [UIButton]()
var wrongBtnsArray = [UIButton]()



override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpWrongAnswers(2)

}

//call this one in viewDidLoad
func setUpWrongAnswers(rightAnswer: Int) {
    var answers = ["answer1","answer2","answer3","answer4"]
    btnsArray = [btn1, btn2, btn3, btn4]

    wrongBtnsArray = btnsArray
    wrongBtnsArray.removeAtIndex(rightAnswer)

    answers.removeAtIndex(rightAnswer)
    wrongAnswers = answers
}

//creates random wrong answer choice
func wrongAnswer(wrongAnswerCount: Int) -> Int {
    let wrongAnswer = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(wrongAnswerCount - 1)))
    return wrongAnswer
}

func hideAnAnswer(wrongAnswer: Int) {
    if wrongAnswers.count >= 2 {
        wrongAnswers.removeAtIndex(wrongAnswer)
        wrongBtnsArray[wrongAnswer].hidden = true
    }
}


@IBAction func hintBtnTapped(sender: UIButton) {
    hideAnAnswer(wrongAnswer(wrongAnswers.count))
}

//You'll probably want to reset the buttons on the next question
func unHideBtns() {
    for btn in btnsArray {
        btn.hidden = false
    }
}
```

That should get you started. Hope it helps!

(edited: Working as is)

Comment: I'm trying it out and getting an error for the func wrongAnswer:  Cannot convert value of type 'Int' to expected argument type 'UInt32'

Comment: Oops! my mistake. You have to wrap wrongAnswerCount in `UInt32`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks that worked! But the hintBtnTapped function is throwing an error:   Cannot call value of non-function type 'Int' for the line  let wAnsToRemove = wrongAnswer(wrongAnswers.count).

Comment: Does arc4random_uniform take a UInt32 as an argument or does it take an In and return a UInt32? If it is the latter, then you should remove the UInt32 cast.

Comment: No, it returns a Int. The UInt32 is needed for arc4random. The problem was the arrays needed to be initialized first. I updated that and changed the `let answers` to `var answers`

Comment: All fixed and tested. (I wrote the first answer on my phone, I learned my lesson). lol

Comment: This code does work when dealing with Ints but the answer is a string.  It has to do with parse.com, even though the answer is between 1-4, they are represented as strings not Ints.

Comment: the Int is the position in the array of answers. This answer applies to you having the answers sorted out. Remember your question was to hide a wrong answer when the hint button is tapped, and this code does that. If you agree you should mark it as correct.

Comment: If you want to get your parse objects sorted into an array of wrong answers and a correct answer string, you can ask a new question. I hope the code I gave you helps.

Comment: Things are often more involved than they seem. I hope you can understand how the code works. Getting your answers into these parameters shouldn't be that difficult. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Array index start from 0.
I presume when you say it hides the right answer button is when the answer is "2", since by your `giveHint` function it will remove index 1 from `answers` array which is "2".

Change your `giveHint` removeAtIndex will do the trick.

```
func giveHint(sender: UIButton){ 
    if self.answer != "1" { 
        answers.removeAtIndex(0) 
        Button1.alpha = 0 
    } else if self.answer != "2" { 
        answers.removeAtIndex(1) 
        Button2.alpha = 0 
    } else if self.answer != "3" { 
        answers.removeAtIndex(2) 
        Button3.alpha = 0 
    } else if self.answer != "4" { 
        answers.removeAtIndex(3) 
        Button4.alpha = 0 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Whoops, I meant to start it at zero. It still didn't work though.